# Access violation on component unit on Delphi

Tags: delphi, serial-port, access-violation

Morning ! I got a little probleme here, every time i try to access on apdcomport1 or on timer_com i get a Violation access, on my .exe and at very low adress... i first think of bad declaration of the component or bad settings on the interface menu, i also try to change my com port.

I would like for my interface a RS232 Communication and i think AdpPortCom i good at this.

error message is : Access Violation at address 00630477 in module 'blabla.exe'. Read address 000003D0.

Here is the declaration of my variable, lib and fonction. (not the main)

[image: Unit with component]

```
interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, OoMisc, AdPort, DefVar, AdExcept,u_msg;

type
  TForm11 = class(TForm)
    ApdComPort1: TApdComPort;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Timer_com: TTimer;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ApdComPort1TriggerData(CP: TObject; TriggerHandle: Word);



  private
    { Déclarations privées }
  public
    { Déclarations publiques }
  end;

var
  Form11: TForm11;
  Data:string ;
  IndiceSortie : integer;
  IndiceAux    : byte;
  Tx_com         : array[1..5000]of ansichar    ;
  Rx_com         : array[1..5000]of ansichar    ;
  handle1 : word;
  procedure open_port_com; forward;
  Procedure StoreConsigne(Var Data: string); forward;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}
uses U_main;
```

Here is one procedure who give's me trouble. (not in the main)

```
procedure open_port_com;
var
  c: Ansichar;
  { handle1 est une variable application }
begin
  with Form11 do
  begin
    try
      ApdComPort1.ComNumber:= 1;//sysdata.PortCom;
      ApdComPort1.open := false;
      ApdComPort1.RS485Mode := false;
      ApdComPort1.open := true;
      ApdComPort1.RemoveAllTriggers;
      c := chr(13);
      { caractère de déclenchement de l'évènement Ondatatrigger }
      handle1 := Form11.ApdComPort1.addDatatrigger(c, false);
      Timer_Com.Enabled := true;

    except
      on Ealreadyopen do { port série déja ouvert }
      begin
        Timer_Com.Enabled := false;
        messagedlg(Str_Err_Com[1] + inttostr(ApdComPort1.comnumber) + Str_Err_Com[2] + Str_Err_Com[3], mTerror, [mbok], 1);
        if messagedlg(Str_Err_Com[6], mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mryes then

      end;
      on Ebadid do { port série innexistant }
      begin
        Timer_com.Enabled := false;
        messagedlg(Str_Err_Com[4] + inttostr(ApdComPort1.comnumber) + Str_Err_Com[5], mTerror, [mbok], 1);
        if messagedlg(Str_Err_Com[6], mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mryes then

      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Lib of my main (Com is the unit upper)

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Vcl.Imaging.pngimage, Vcl.Grids,

  U_Msg,DefVar,U_ModeMDP,U_Alerte,u_ValidationNet,U_ConsigneLancement,U_ArrUrgence,U_FinDeCycle,
  U_ConfirmFerme,   com    ,Vcl.WinXPickers, Vcl.Menus, Vcl.Imaging.jpeg;
```

I Would like to know how if it is possible to track and resolve easily this type of error.

Comment: Is AdpComport1 a component dropped on a form? If not when to you create the instance. To start debugging, put a break point on the line "ApdComPort1.ComNumber:= 1;" and when the break point is hit, check if AdpComPort1 is nil. I guess it is!

Comment: Already done and yes it is not returning anything

Comment: Where do you call ``open_port_com``? MainForm.OnCreate? If yes, then check the creation order of your forms in the project options. It's very likely that your Form11 just isn't created yet!

Comment: You'r true My form11 is not in the automated created form ! so i need to change my unit fill into a vcl one ?

Comment: You can create it yourself, that's up to you

Comment: i create a VCL fill instead of a unit fill and i have not the error yet ! thank's !

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Normally, when you want to use non-visual components from other parts of your program, use a `DataModule`. Like in your example it must also be created before use. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625721/what-is-the-datamodule-dm-in-delphi

Comment: @DelphiCoder my com was a unit fill so technically it cannot be create as a form (like a DefVar fill), so i create it as a secondary blank window and the form is goodly create

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your concept of "unit fill". I understand you create a blank form just as a container not meant to be shown. In that case, create a TDataModule instead of a TForm. The data module can be created automatically or you can create it manually before you use the components dropped on it it in anyway. Be aware of the order of automatic creation to not use something not created yet!

Comment: After the message of @LURD I've create a TdataModule much better as i see.